# How to access *.lnk files, (shortcuts) from a UWP app

Tags: windows, uwp-xaml

I would like to be able to access *.lnk files from any folder on my desktop.
I know that Windows.Storage cannot access *.lnk files but I can read and access them from from Win32 or System.IO in WPF apps.
Is there a way for me to incorporate FindFirstFileEx() into my app without getting access permission errors?
I have seen articles on FullTrustProcessLauncher Class and CustomCapabilities settings but no examples using Kernal32 methods, or advice on even if this would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but no examples using Kernal32 methods

For this scenario, you could use desktop-bridge desktop extension to approach, for detail steps please refer stfan's blog [UWP with Desktop Extension](https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/06/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-1/).

For using Kernal32 methods, please refer pinvoke [document](https://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/FindFirstFileEx.html).

```
public enum FINDEX_INFO_LEVELS
{
    FindExInfoStandard = 0,
    FindExInfoBasic = 1
}
public enum FINDEX_SEARCH_OPS
{
    FindExSearchNameMatch = 0,
    FindExSearchLimitToDirectories = 1,
    FindExSearchLimitToDevices = 2
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public struct WIN32_FIND_DATA
{
    public uint dwFileAttributes;
    public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME ftCreationTime;
    public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME ftLastAccessTime;
    public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME ftLastWriteTime;
    public uint nFileSizeHigh;
    public uint nFileSizeLow;
    public uint dwReserved0;
    public uint dwReserved1;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)]
    public string cFileName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 14)]
    public string cAlternateFileName;
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern IntPtr FindFirstFileEx(
 string lpFileName,
 FINDEX_INFO_LEVELS fInfoLevelId,
 out WIN32_FIND_DATA lpFindFileData,
 FINDEX_SEARCH_OPS fSearchOp,
 IntPtr lpSearchFilter,
 int dwAdditionalFlags);
```

Comment: @CoCalceDew From what I have gleamed so far, it's possible to launch another app from my uwp app using desktop-bridge/desktop extension. What I would like to do is build my uwp app with a DLL library that has all my Import code for my Kernal32 methods. Can I make my uwp app a fulltrust app?

Comment: No, you can't make uwp  as fulltrust app. the fulltrust only support desktop extension part.